# \n appears in file path even if it is not given

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to read a file path from a csv file and storing it in the form of a variable. The function reads the path correctly but when I am using that variable, it puts an extra "\n" in the file path. Here is my code.

```
    `def input_path(input_file):
         next(input_file)

         for line in input_file:
             row_heading = line.split(",")
             input_path_value = row_heading[0]
             weather_file_path = row_heading[1]

         return input_path_value, weather_file_path`
```

I am getting the following error:[\n adds to the file path before "Ahmedabad"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcX50.png)

Comment: Why different variable names `row headinng` , `row_heading` and `row_heading_`. Is it a mistake or is it the way you meant it to be?

Comment: Sorry It was my typing error. I corrected

Comment: You probably want to look at the `strip()` function, and also `os.path.join()`.

Comment: You may be better off using the built-in csv module; this avoids problems with quoted commas, for example; or newlines.